# MediaRouter android programming

Tags: android, mediarouter

I have a problem with `MediaRouter` for an android application,i followed the android API guide for `MediaRouter` but when i run the application,on toolbar doesn't appear any button.

```
public class MediaRouterPlaybackActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaRouteSelector mSelector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.miracast);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        // Create a route selector for the type of routes your app supports.
        mSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                // These are the framework-supported intents
                .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        // Inflate the menu and configure the media router action provider.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mediarouter, menu);
        // Attach the MediaRouteSelector to the menu item
        MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider =
                (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(
                        mediaRouteMenuItem);
        // Attach the MediaRouteSelector that you built in onCreate()
        mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mSelector);
        // Return true to show the menu.
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the code of toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#4696e5"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
```

Comment: Have you got success? If not yet please try changing this `(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK` to `(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO`. 
They have written here,
Use secondary output to send content to wireless-enabled music systems or video displays. To enable the discovery and selection of these devices, you need to add the `CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO` or `CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO` control categories to the MediaRouteSelector. You also need to create and handle your own `Presentation` dialog. Link:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case it was becasue the button is only shown if there is some media receiver detected such as Chromecast or a custom media route. If you don't have any device to send the button doesn't show.

Comment: If you want to show some hit text when there aren't any routes available, you can use `MediaRouter#isRouteAvailable(android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector, int)`

[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.html#isRouteAvailable(android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector, int) )